# Add <br> in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

How to add new line in angularjs. I have this code in my controller:

```
$scope.newLine = '<br>';
  $scope.getID =funtion(number){
    for( var key in $scope.myData){
      var obj = $scope.myData[key];
        if(obj['seat_no'] == number){
          return obj['passenger_name'] + $scope.newLine + obj['ticket_no'];
         }
     }

  };
```

And this in my html:

```
<table class ="table table-bordered">
<colgroup span="7"></colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="tr in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="td in tr track by $index">
      {{ td }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The output is :

```
1       |  Name Ticket No.
```

And I want the output of:

```
1       |  Name
        |  Ticket No
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS has XSS protection build in by default, so you need to tell it to render the text as HTML.

```
<span ng-bind-html="td"></span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need use: [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3AngBindHtml)